# Check if checkbox is checked MVC controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

On my MVC View I have a few checkboxes:

```
<form method="POST" id="formRegistration" action="Registration/SubmitRegistration" > 
//Other code...
    <input name="test1" type="checkbox" />
    <input name="test2" type="checkbox"  />
</form>
```

On the controller I get- using a POST request- the data and I insert it to the DataBase:

```
public void AddRegistered(Registration r)
{
//Other code...
     dParameters.Add("test1", r.test1.ToString());
     dParameters.Add("test2", r.test2.ToString());
//Other code...
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting a `false` value even if the checkbox is checked.

Wham am I missing?

Comment: Use `Html.CheckBoxFor` instead of using manual HTML.

Comment: It's a requirement to use manual HTML, I can't use Razor.

Comment: A checkbox post back the value of its control is checked (or nothing if not checked. Your setting `value="false"` so all it can ever submit is `false`. And if you not gong to use the `HtmlHelper` methods, then don't bother using mvc since you will never get correct model binding.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to delete the `value="false"` it was one of my testings, would you be able to explain more what you mean by: _And if you not gong to use the HtmlHelper methods, then don't bother using mvc since you will never get correct model binding._ It's very important for me to fully understand what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I generate manual forms in ASP.Net all the time, not to mention post into MVC controllers using javascript etc. Saying that the only thing that can post data into MVC is `HtmlHelper` is naive.

Comment: @caesay Where did I say _the only thing that can post data into MVC is HtmlHelper_?

Comment: @user3378165, Now the only thing that will be posted is `"on"` which cannot be bound to `bool`

Comment: @StephenMuecke: You said that you shouldn't bother using MVC if you're not using `HtmlHelper` because you will never get the correct model binding. **????** There are loads of reasons to use Razor/MVC and lots of ways to submit data and none of them have anything to do with `HtmlHelper`.

Comment: @caesay. Using the `HtmlHelper` methods has everything to do with model binding! (unless you want to write dozens of line of code every time you write an input manually)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: You're still being extremely short sighted, and it doesn't require dozens of lines of codes every time you write an input - it requires a few lines of code, one time, in one place (see my answer). Also, checkbox is literally the only `input` affected by this.

Comment: @caesay, Then sorry, but you do not understand how the `HtmlHelper` methods work to generate the correct html for correct 2-way model binding.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: the `HtmlHelper` as name implies - is a helper. It is more elegant and makes code more readable and it is less error prone - but it is not mandatory at all. And, for simple cases like this one, the model binder logic is super simple - so really not much benefit on insisting to use `HtmlHelper`.

Comment: @Dusan, The `HtmlHelper` methods involve dozens of line of code that ensure correct 2-way model binding including setting (in the case of a checkbox), the `checked` attribute by first checking values for `ModelState`, then from `ViewData` and finally from the actual value of the property. No its not mandatory, but not using it will never give correct model binding without writing massive amounts of extra code in the view. (then of course there is all the code for implementing client side validation etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Also, when you need to output `html` with custom attributes and style, the use of `HtmlHelper` becomes less readable and more cumbersome in contrast with plain and simple html. The `HtmlHelper` suffers similar problems like web forms controls - it abstracts html which is wrong approach for any non-trivial output.

Comment: @Dusan, Whats wrong with `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SomeBool, new { @class = "xxx", ... })`? And asp.net-core-mvc provides `TagHelpers` as an alternative

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Don't know - ask your web designer who does not speak razor? Or better, ask him to fine tune `html` of something like the `@Html.Grid(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing you should do it take a look at the actual data being sent to the server with chrome debug tools or similar. What you might find is that your checkbox value will be set to `on` if checked, or it will be missing completely if un-checked.

One suggestion in the comments was `@Html.CheckBoxFor`, but this also suffers the fact that nothing will be sent if the checkbox is un-checked and in specific situations that can still become a problem.

You have two solutions - fix it on the client, or fix it on the server.

**Fix it on the client**:
To do this, you'll need to (with javascript) add a hidden field for every checkbox. Forgive me, I'm not by an editor to test it out but it might look something like this (from memory):

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(el) {
    var hidden = $('<input type="hidden" />');
    hidden.name = el.name;
    el.after(hidden);
    el.on("change", function(el) {
       hidden.value = el.checked ? "true" : "false";
    });
});
```

**Fix it on the server:** 
To do this, you'll need to create a custom `PropertyBinder` which recognizes `on` as a boolean `true`. This would be set on a property-attribute level. You could alternatively override the global `ModelBinder` to do this so you don't need to specifically annotate a property for this to work.

---

Personally, I prefer the "fix it on the client" method, because you will get either `true` or `false` posted back to the server every time which is what you'd expect and is the closest to the way that `HtmlHelper` does it.

Comment: _nothing will be sent if the checkbox is un-checked_ is simply wrong! - `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` correctly generates 2 inputs, a checkbox with `Value="True` and a hidden input with `value="False"`

Comment: Maybe you're right about that, I can't check right now - but I've had to ditch `HtmlHelper` and do this manually before because I wasn't getting false values posted back to the server. Could be a separate issue, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `value` attribute:

```
<input name="test1" type="checkbox" value="true" />
<input name="test2" type="checkbox" value="true" />
```

As simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use HtmlHelper class you can do like this

```
<form method="POST" id="formRegistration" action="Registration/SubmitRegistration" > 

<input name="test1" type="checkbox" value="@Model.test1" />
<input name="test2" type="checkbox" value="@Model.test2"  />
```

test1 and test2 should be in your model class.

Comment: You can also do `<input name="@( nameof(@Model.test1 ) )" />` as well - though this won't work for nested/child views or complex view-models.